# requestAnimationFrame polyfill: what's the element parameter for?

Tags: javascript, parameters, element, requestanimationframe

I am using the requestAnimationFrame polyfill by Erik Möller (fixes from Paul Irish and Tino Zijdel) and I was wondering what is the second parameter called "element" for.

Here is the code:

```
(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame']
                                   || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
              timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}());
```

So my question is about this line:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
```

What does "element" do?

Thank you very much in advance,

Joan

Answer (score 0):

According to the [W3C draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#requestAnimationFrame), no `element` parameter is passed to this function. At least for now.

As you can see, there is [an issue](http://www.w3.org/2010/webperf/track/issues/4) which suggest the addition of such parameter. 
This issue was considered *not necessary for the first version of this spec.* and has been closed.

I think you can just ignore this parameter.